# filling a toolStripDropDownButton

Tags: c#, winforms

what i'm basicaly wan to do, is add somme items in a toolstripdropdownbutton.
What i did was:

```
toolStripDropDownButtonColor.DropDownItems.Add("text", null, ChangeTextColor);
```

But now i need to change the fore en the back color of those items, so i saw that i can use ToolStripItem. And here i can set the propertys i want to,

But: How do i declare sommething like that? i have sommething like this:

```
ToolStripItem fs;
  fs.Text = c.ToString();
  fs.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromKnownColor(c);
  fs.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromKnownColor(c);
  fs.Click += ChangeTextColor;

  toolStripDropDownButtonColor.DropDownItems.Add(fs);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToolStripItem` is abstract class, so You can't declare object of this class. In this case, You can use `ToolStripMenuItem` instead:

```
  ToolStripItem fs = new ToolStripMenuItem();
  fs.Text = c.ToString();
  fs.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromKnownColor(c);
  fs.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromKnownColor(c);
  fs.Click += ChangeTextColor;

  toolStripDropDownButtonColor.DropDownItems.Add(fs);
```